# React Js Child Cannot receive parents props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

may parent is APP.JS and child is Dasboard.js  im trying to pass user id from App.js to my child dashboard.js problem is i can only get the props on render but at the componentDidmount i cannot access it anymore how this this possible? can explain or give me link to read why this thing happen i thought that if u pass the props from parent child can receive it , with this case only work in render not in componentDidMount example below

[image]

**App.js Code**

```
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
       
        this.state = {
           success:null,
           results:'',
           
        }
       this.CheckLoginStatus = this.CheckLoginStatus.bind(this)
      }
    
      componentDidMount(){
        this.CheckLoginStatus()
      }
      
      CheckLoginStatus(){
          const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
          const bearer = "Bearer"
          if(token === null){
              this.setState({success:false})
          }
         axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/details',{
           headers:{
             Authorization:bearer+ ' ' +token
           }
         })
         .then(response => {
          
          if(response.status === 200){
           this.setState({success:true,results:response.data.success})
        } 
    
         }).catch(err => {
           localStorage.clear()
         })
    
      }
     
      render() {
    
        return (
          <Router>
          <Switch>
          <Route  path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Layout>
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact render={props => (
            <Dashboard {...props} status={this.state.success} results={this.state.results} />
          )}
          />
          
          </Layout>
          </Switch>
          </Router>
        
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default App
```

Comment: could you add the app.js and dashboard component code.

Comment: okay hold on ill edit the post

Comment: dashboard i only did componentDidMount then inside console.log same as the picture

Comment: use componentDidUpdate and get the value in this lifecycle.

Comment: alright thank you .. it work nice to know the use for componentDidUpdate can u post answer so that i can accept it.. again thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle, as in the initials render the `result state` will be empty.  You are getting the result data in `app.js` `componnetdidMount` lifecycle.

And when the dashboard mounts the first time, data of result will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.CheckLoginStatus()
      }

     CheckLoginStatus = async () => {
          const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
          const bearer = "Bearer"
          if(token === null){
              this.setState({success:false})
          }
        await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/details',{
           headers:{
             Authorization:bearer+ ' ' +token
           }
         })
         .then(response => {

          if(response.status === 200){
           this.setState({success:true,results:response.data.success})
        } 

         }).catch(err => {
           localStorage.clear()
         })

      }
```